# Angular - Undefined Values in subscribe return

Tags: angular, undefined, subscribe

I am developing a form, where I will get value from a webapi and show to user.. Ok.. all part os get data from webapi are ok. Subscribe are returning the right Json, without problem

this is the angular program:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ErrorMsgComponent } from '../../shared/error-msg/error-msg.component';

import { UserallService } from 'src/app/services/userall.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserAll } from '../../interfaces/userall';

import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdet',
  templateUrl: './userdet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdet.component.css']
})
export class UserdetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() userall: UserAll =  {} as UserAll;
  @ViewChild(ErrorMsgComponent) errorMsgComponent: ErrorMsgComponent;
  @ViewChild('f', {static: false}) myForm: NgForm;

  public isDisabled = true;
  public btnName = 'Alterar dados';
  private userallOld = this.userall;

  constructor(private userAllService: UserallService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserData();
  }

  public editarForm(): void {
    this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;

    if (this.isDisabled) {
      this.userall = this.userallOld;
      this.btnName = 'Alterar dados';
    }
    else {
      this.btnName = 'Cancelar';
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.modUserAll(this.userall);
  }

  modUserAll(userall: UserAll): void {
    this.userAllService.modUserAll(userall)
      .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.errorMsgComponent.setOk('Usuário alterado com Sucesso');
        this.myForm.resetForm();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errorMsgComponent.setError('Falha ao alterar usuario.');
      });
  }

  getUserData(): void {
    this.userAllService.getUser(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserId'))
      .subscribe(
      (result: UserAll) => {
        this.userall = result;
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.name);
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserId'));
        console.log(this.userall.name);
        this.myForm.name = this.userall.name;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errorMsgComponent.setError('Falha ao ler dados do usuario.');
      });
  }
}
```

this is the instance for userall:

```
export interface UserAll {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  zipCode: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
 }
```

and this is the returns from console log..
console.log(result);

> [{…}]0:
> address1: "xxxxxxxx"
> address2: "yyyyyyy"
> city: "fffffffffff"
> country: "Brazil"
> id: 1
> name: "sjh fsdkjfh sakjhf "
> phoneNumber: "+5531969696969"
> user: null
> userId: "380de5fe-711a-4b4a-9130-4c86684c38df"
> zipCode: "6969696969"
> **proto**: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)

```
    console.log(result.name);
```

userdet.component.ts:67 undefined

```
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserId'));
```

userdet.component.ts:68 380de5fe-711a-4b4a-9130-4c86684c38df

```
    console.log(this.userall.name);
```

userdet.component.ts:69 undefined

i am confuse, because the json are returned by the subscribe, but the result.name is undefine.. WTH?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is an array with objects returned. Try result[0].name

Comment: This worked for me... but i do not understand, the logic is the same in another proccess,a nd i do not used array to return values... [0].. but anyway, thanks for help...

Comment: yes you should check that. It might be defined in the array or a wrong function call.